# Background job added. Need status and and to show user the details

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job, rails-activejob

I have a task on my site that runs in an admin area, therefore only gets run by me, and it takes about 10 minutes to run. I have just converted this to run as a background job and it does so nicely.

My question is, is there some sort of gem I can use that can easily allow me to bring the status of a particular job to a specific view in my app.  Eg, to show whether it is running, if it's errored, if the last one was successful etc?

I have using Delayed Job with ActiveJob. The task will only be run by me and there should never be more than one of its task running at the same time.  The job also has a uniquely named queue.

Answer (score 1):

You can find out if a job is running by checking the `locked_at` or `locked_by` column.

You can check if a job has failed with the `failed_at` column.

If you don't have enough info about the job with the default columns, you can add more columns to the table and set them when the job is run. For example, you can add a `user_id` to track which user the job relates to.

Reference: [Delayed Job Table Details](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job#gory-details)